# Access Child Screen Props From React Navigation Top Tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using Typescript and since this question is more theoretical, I will only post the necessary code.
I have a material top tab navigation looking like this:

> TabNavigator.tsx

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator<GameTabParamList>();

const GameTabs: FC = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName={Screens.HOME_SCREEN}
      tabBarPosition="bottom"
      screenOptions={{
        lazy: true,
        tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'},
        swipeEnabled: false, // This should be equal to props that are found in the multiple screens
      }}
      backBehavior='none'>
      <Tab.Screen
        name={Screens.AVAILABLE_PRIZES_SCREEN}
        component={AvailablePrizesScreen}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name={Screens.HOME_SCREEN} component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name={Screens.WON_PRIZES_SCREEN}
        component={WonPrizesScreen}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

> HomeScreen.txs

```
const HomeScreen: FC = () => {
  const {
    isInitialized,
    isLoading,
    adShowing,
    playGame,
    localCount,
    isAnimationPlaying,
    winAnimationRef,
    handleWinAnimationFinished,
    isFlashAnimationPlaying,
    navToSettingsScreen,
    displayPrizeId,
    displayPrizeTitle,
    displayPrizeDesc,
    displayPrizeTier,
    displayPrizeType,
    isShowingPrize,
    handleHidePrize,
    handleFlashAnimationFinished,
    navigation,
  } = useHomeScreen();

...
}
```

The goal is to make the swipeEnabled equal to the HomeScreen's `isloading` and `isInitialized` variables. So it should look like this:

> TabNavigator.tsx

```
      screenOptions={{
        lazy: true,
        tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'},
        swipeEnabled: !isLoading || !isInitialized, // <-- how do I get this here?
      }}
```

The problem is, how do I get the isLoading and isInitialized variables from the `HomeScreen` component to the `GameTabs` component?

Answer (score 1):

Create another state inside `GameTabs` component and pass it's `setState` function to each screen component to keep track of `isLoading` and `isInitialized` variables.

**TabNavigator.tsx**

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator<GameTabParamList>();

const GameTabs: FC = () => {

    const [swipeEnabled, setSwipeEnabled] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName={Screens.HOME_SCREEN}
      tabBarPosition="bottom"
      screenOptions={{
        lazy: true,
        tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'},
        swipeEnabled: swipeEnabled, 
      }}
      backBehavior='none'>
      <Tab.Screen
        name={Screens.AVAILABLE_PRIZES_SCREEN}
        component={AvailablePrizesScreen}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name={Screens.HOME_SCREEN} render={() => <HomeScreen setSwipeEnabled={setSwipeEnabled}/>} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name={Screens.WON_PRIZES_SCREEN}
        component={WonPrizesScreen}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**HomeScreen.txs**

Inside `HomeScreen`, use `useEffect` to set `swipeEnabled` state having `isLoading` and `isInitialized` variables inside the dependency array of the `useEffect`.

```
const HomeScreen: FC = ({ setSwipeEnabled }) => {
    const {
      isInitialized,
      isLoading,
      adShowing,
      playGame,
      localCount,
      isAnimationPlaying,
      winAnimationRef,
      handleWinAnimationFinished,
      isFlashAnimationPlaying,
      navToSettingsScreen,
      displayPrizeId,
      displayPrizeTitle,
      displayPrizeDesc,
      displayPrizeTier,
      displayPrizeType,
      isShowingPrize,
      handleHidePrize,
      handleFlashAnimationFinished,
      navigation,
    } = useHomeScreen();

    useEffect(() => {
        setSwipeEnabled(!isLoading || !isInitialized);
      }, [isLoading, isInitialized]);
  
  ...
  }
```

Comment: Great idea, I don't know why I didn't think of this. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: yes, this answer can be used for generic purposes.

Comment: Yes, this does work for general purposes, however, in this specific situation I believe that my solution is more optimal since I don't rely on updating the state each time that `isLoading` and `isInitialized` is changed. But I don't think the performance difference would make much of a difference however.

Comment: Yes, in your case, your solution is the best way to do it. But in some cases, we have to use the react way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

This is one solution that works, but @Kavindu Vindika offered a solution that may be cleaner.

### Initial Answer

I found the soloution. Turns out, the navigation prop that get's passed to each screen has a `setOptions` method. So you can simply call that when each screen gets mounted. For example, after I fetch the navigation prop I simply did:

```
  navigation.setOptions({swipeEnabled: !isLoading});
```

This solved my problem.